# 'numpy.int64' has no len()

Tags: python, list, numpy, dataframe

Error:

```
TypeError: object of type 'numpy.int64' has no len()
```

Code:

```
import numpy as np

def apk(actual, predicted, k=10):

    if len(predicted)>k: # here is the error
        predicted = predicted[:k]

    score = 0.0
    num_hits = 0.0

    for i,p in enumerate(predicted):
        if p in actual and p not in predicted[:i]:
            num_hits += 1.0
            score += num_hits / (i+1.0)

    if not actual:
        return 1.0

    return score / min(len(actual), k)

def mapk(actual, predicted, k=10):
    print(type(predicted))
    >>> <class 'list'> # here is predicted also from the value list
    return np.mean([apk(a,p,k) for a,p in zip(actual, predicted)])




x = list(df_new['id'].to_numpy())
y = list(re['id'].to_numpy())

print(type(y))
>>> <class 'list'>
# So y is a list and not like later 'numpy.int64'
mapk(x,y)
```

When I start the following call I get the following error, how do I resolve it?
When I do the following, I get the length `len(y)`
How do I solve this error? I am very much looking forward to answers.

Comment: Is `predicted` *always* a list?   If you're only predicting one value, does whatever is predicting still yield a list with only one value, or does it just return the value?  From what you provided here, we cannot reproduce, and thus can't really help besides making wild suppositions like this.

Answer (score 1):

You're iterating through `predicted` in this line:

```
return np.mean([apk(a,p,k) for a,p in zip(actual, predicted)])
```

`predicted` is a list, but `p` is just an element of that list.

In the scope of `apk`, `predicted` *is* `p` (not the `predicted` from `mapk`) - and thus, apparently, `int64`.

Answer (score 0):

### How to debug your code:

With the informations you provide, the problem is that the type of `predicted` is `numpy.int64`. And an `int` has, indeed, no len. I suppose that `predicted` should be a `list` ?

Try to print the type of `predicted` before the line where you get the error:

```
def apk(actual, predicted, k=10):
    print(type(predicted)) # Add this code
    if len(predicted)>k: # here is the error
```

The error appears in the `apk` function.

### The line causing the error:

And @Daniel F explains in his answer why `predicted` is not of type `list`:

Because what you pass as an argument as the parameter named `predicted` to the `apk` function is NOT the variable `predicted` you have in the `mapk` function. In fact, you pass the variable `p` to `apk`, which is not the `list` named `predicted`.
And, from the error message, we deduce that `p` is of type `numpy.64`.

This is the line where you pass `p` as an argument for the parameter named `predicted`, to your function `apk`: `[apk(a,p,k) for a,p in zip(actual, predicted)]`

If you change this code to this (I'm not saying you *should* do this, because from what you provide we can't do more than making assumptions):

```
[apk(a,predicted,k) for a,p in zip(actual, predicted)]
```

Then, you will not pass `p`, but you will pass `predicted` as an argument for the parameter named `predicted`, to your function `apk`.

### Detail explanation on what is going on :

I'll go in depth, my excuses if it seems too exagerated.

I'll will explain here the line `[apk(a,predicted,k) for a,p in zip(actual, predicted)]`:

Here is a simple example of how `zip` works:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
c = list(zip(a,b))
```

`c` will be a `list` of `tuple`s.

Each `tuple` will contains two variables of type `int`.
Values of `c` : [(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]

So when you'll iterate through `c` you will get :

- (1, 4) at the first iteration
- (2, 5) at the second iteration
- and (3, 6) at the third iteration.

Example code:

```
for a_tuple in c:
    a,p = a_tuple
    print(a) # 1 at 1st iter, 2 at 2nd,and 3 at 3rd
    print(p) # 4 at 1st iter, 5 at 2nd,and 6 at 3rd
```

When we write:

```
a,p = (1,2)
```

we will assigne the first element of the `tuple` to `a` and the second to `p`.
So `a == 1` and `p == 2`.

If we write `a,b,c = (1,2,3)`: `a == 1`, `b == 2`,  and `c == 3`.

Now, we will decompose your list comprehension as a for loop:

If you set `actual = [1,2,3]` and `predicted = [4,5,6]`, then, writing:

```
[apk(a,p,k) for a,p in zip(actual, predicted)]
```

is the same as writing:

```
k = 2
zipped = zip(actual, predicted)
# list(zipped) == [(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]

for a,p in zipped:
    apk(a,p,k) # p == 4 at 1st iter, 5 at 2nd,and 6 at 3rd. p is an element of a tuple of the zipped list
```

To conclude: you have to determine what sould be the types of `actual` and `predited`, **inside** (in its scope) the function named `apk`.

Comment: But if I type `print(type(y))` it is `<class 'list'>` .

Comment: And also in the method `mapk` it is `<class 'list'>`

Comment: The problem is in the function ```apk```